# Can MS-Word open encrypted ODT-Files

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice

Is it possible to open LibreOffice encrypted documents using MS-Word 2010? The data format is odt and the password is known.
Is the encryption secure?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. If no one will came out with the answer you can always install libreoffice on the windows machine and open the file with this suite. It's  [Free & Open Source](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/libreoffice/)... :-)

Comment: the problem is I cannot install anything write now :( But need to know the answer...

Comment: You may find interesting to [read here](http://askubuntu.com/a/326161/196535). I cannot verify it at moment, BTW you can always ask to export the `odt` file in a word format that you read for sure, then compress and encrypt the file with something like [zip](http://www.howtogeek.com/203590/how-to-create-secure-encrypted-zip-or-7z-archives-on-any-operating-system) or [winzip](http://kb.winzip.com/help/help_encryption.htm) (or a in more secure way  with [GPG](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-commandline-encryption-tools/)), finally you can open it again in the windows computer...

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice uses encryption to enforce password protection on documents. The encryption algorithm used varies between versions of LibreOffice and the document format specification.

For example, LibreOffice 3.5 uses AES-256 for password protected files in the ODF 1.2 and ODF 1.2 Extended file formats. See [LibreOffice 3.5 release notes](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/3.5#Different_Encryption_Algorithm) for more info.

So the security of your document is subject to the complexity of your password and the strength of the encryption algorithm. You either need to know/guess/brute-force the password, or break the encryption algorithm through potential vulnerabilities.

As to the compatibility with Microsoft Word... Microsoft Word for Office 365 (16.0.10827.20118) cannot handle encrypted ODT documents saved by LibreOffice Writer (6.1.2.1), with a known password. Just tested.

[image: Word can't open encrypted ODT files]